# Spring amqp not publishing message to the queue but to Exchange

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to test & benchmark spring-amqp for RabbitMQ with multiple queues so I was creating rabbit template for each queue and using it to send message. The message sent is successful and I can see a message published in the exchange but I don't see anything in the queue. I am guessing it's very minor setting but can't figure it out.

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="banchmarkConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="benchmarkAmqpHost"/>
        <property name="username" ref="benchmarkAmqpUser"/>
        <property name="password" ref="benchmarkAmqpPass"/>
        <property name="virtualHost" ref="benchmarkAmqpVHost"/>
        <property name="channelCacheSize" value="10"/>
</bean>
<rabbit:template id="benchmarkAmqpTemplate"
        connection-factory="banchmarkConnectionFactory"
        exchange="my_exchange"
        queue="BenchmarkQueue"
        routing-key="BenchmarkQueue" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="banchmarkConnectionFactory"/>
<rabbit:queue name="BenchmarkQueue" auto-delete="true" durable="false" auto-declare="true"/>
```

This is my code which uses the `benchmarkAmqpTemplate` to publish to the queue.

```
public class publishMessage {
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate benchmarkAmqpTemplate;

    protected void publish(String payload) {
        benchmarkAmqpTemplate.setQueue("BenchmarkQueue");
        benchmarkAmqpTemplate.convertAndSend("my_exchange", "BenchmarkQueue", payload);

    }
}
```

When I used the HelloWorld [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/helloworld) it did publish a message in the queue so was wondering if I am doing something wrong.
**UPDATE**
I was able to solve this by adding `direct-exchange` tag in my context xml. My full xml looks like this:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsdhttp://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

<bean id="banchmarkConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="benchmarkAmqpHost"/>
            <property name="username" ref="benchmarkAmqpUser"/>
            <property name="password" ref="benchmarkAmqpPass"/>
            <property name="virtualHost" ref="benchmarkAmqpVHost"/>
            <property name="channelCacheSize" value="10"/>
    </bean>
    <rabbit:template id="benchmarkAmqpTemplate"
            connection-factory="banchmarkConnectionFactory"
            exchange="my_exchange"
            queue="BenchmarkQueue"
            routing-key="BenchmarkQueue" />
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="banchmarkConnectionFactory"/>
    <rabbit:queue name="BenchmarkQueue" auto-delete="true" durable="false" auto-declare="true"/>
    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="my_exchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="BenchmarkQueue" key="BenchmarkQueue" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, but it looks like you misunderstood AMQP protocol a bit.

The message is published to the `Exchange` with the proper `routingKey`.
The publisher (`RabbitTemplate`) doesn't need to know about queues at all.

The `queue` is a part of receiver, subscriber to the `queue`.

There is one more feature in between - `binding`. The `queue` is bound to the `Exchange` under the appropriate `routingKey`. One queue can be bound to several exchanges with different routing keys. By default all queues are bound to the default exchange (`""`) with routingKeys equal to their `name`s.

Please, refer for more info to the RabbitMQ site.

Comment: Thanks @Artem & @Gary. So in the xml above I have provided the binding but still I can't see it in RabbitMQ Mgmt console. When I start my application my queue always shows default exchange binding and not `my_exchange` as specified in my xml. I also don't see any queued messages there.

Comment: To make them declared on the Broker you should `AmqpAdmin`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#broker-configuration

Comment: You need to show the updated XML. Also take a look at the logs, the RabbitAdmin logs all the declarations.

Comment: Thanks Artem & Gary. I had the default admin but didn't have the `direct-exchange`. I have the updated xml above and its working! Do you guys think it looks good? Also without the `direct-exchange` tag my RabbitAdmin logs was only showing `accepting AMQP connection <0.11532.2> (127.0.0.1:49437 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)`

Comment: @Artem @Gary I have another question regarding the concurrency. If I have the above connection factory with `channelCacheSize=10` and multiple requests come to my tomcat application, will all of them be sharing the same connection/channel or only connection will be shared and more channels will be created and added to the pool? Coming form simple java rabbit client application I had to **synchronize my threads** for getting the channel which was painful. While reading spring-amqp docs I read this so thought should ask you guys.

Comment: Even if channels are shared from the pool they are mutually exclusive by use. If your requests excess the pool size the new raw channel will be created on demand and closed after usage properly (or returned to the pool, if there is a room :-)).

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments; open a new question.